# Story or feature file static analysis tool (Jbheave or Cucumber)

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber

I am exploring idea or any existing tool or utility which help to statically  analyse story files for  my  project where static analysis tool  check correctness  of  story  files

Comment: What do you mean by "Correctness"?

Comment: You may want to search for a Gherkin Linter. It sounds as if you are asking about suggestions for a tool. Unfortunately, your questions doesn't contain a question so I can only guess.